# Directus deployment on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: apache2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, directus, ebextensions

I cloned Directus 8 from [github](https://github.com/directus/directus). I run it in my local server. It worked fine without any problems.

Then I uploaded code to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (PHP, apache). but it showed 500 Internal Server Error.

error log: `/var/www/html/directus/public/.htaccess: <IfModule not allowed here`

I added `.ebextensions/setup.config` file to my root folder, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322218/7765316).

```
files:          
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_rewrite.conf": 
     mode: "644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       AllowOverride All
```

but my Beanstalk said `Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0f6...'. Aborting the operation.` and went to **degrading** state.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is for Directus 8 (PHP)**

Tried almost all ways of apache settings using .ebextensions and .platform nothing worked.

Then tried **NGINX** with custom .platform configs. **It worked**. Answering the steps which I did, may be helpful to someone else, who has the same problem

---

1. Directus docs has some [configs for NGINEX](https://v8.docs.directus.io/advanced/server-setup.html#nginx), go through it
2. create `nginex.conf` file under `.platform/nginx` folder

[image: platform/nginx]

3. we are going to replace existing `nginex.conf` inside the beanstalk. copy existing `nginex.conf` using ssh to ec2 instance and add the custom configs mentioned in the docs and paste it to our newly created `.platform/nginx/nginex.conf`

below is my custom `.platform/nginx/nginex.conf`

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    32136;    
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}    
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location /admin {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html?$args;
        }

        location /thumbnail {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /thumbnail/index.php?$args;
        }

        # Deny direct access to php files in extensions
        location /extensions/.+\.php$ {
            deny all;
        }
        
        # All uploads files (originals) cached for a year
        location ~* /uploads/([^/]+)/originals/(.*) {
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000";
        }

        # Serve php, html and cgi files as text file
        location ~* /uploads/.*\.(php|phps|php5|htm|shtml|xhtml|cgi.+)?$ {
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        }

        # Deny access to any file starting with .ht,
        # including .htaccess and .htpasswd
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;                
        }        

        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }
}
```

4. done, when we uploading it, beanstalk will automatically replace our custom `nginex.conf` with existing `nginex.conf`. (note: we can add the changes only instead of replacing, but it didn't work at the time I tried)